# Synonyms: amazon-mws and mws

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I believe that [amazon-mws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-mws) and [mws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mws) are identical. They are referring to the same thing.

I would suggest keeping [amazon-mws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-mws) for clarity.

I do not have the rep to do this myself, or I would.

Comment: I guess it would be better merged than synonymized. Well, not mine to do either way.

Comment: Ok, I new here. I was under the impression that merge was the english form or at least a synonym of synonymized. What happens when they're merged?

Comment: Merging is a mod-only operation. While synonymizing redirects a tag and corrects it on submission, merging destroys one tag and retags with the other. It's aa question of judgement which is more appropriate... and in this case, neither is really wrong.

Comment: I summon the mods to do as they see fit...

Comment: Best wait with it. For a week or so, thus anyone who wants gets a chance to chime in. It's not urgent. Also, that way you get to collect more upvotes (though no rep).

Answer (score 3):

Bumping this in the hope a moderator can see it. I've spent the last few days tidying up and removing the [mws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mws) tag, mainly updating to [amazon-mws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-mws)

Can a mod now please synonmise or 'merge' mws to prevent further questions using it?

Comment: I'm not sure if a tag with 0 questions can still be made a synonym.

Comment: If that is the case, then would be worth temporarily retagging one so that a mod can create a synonym. Otherwise we're perpetually chasing our tails with these pointless retagging exercises.  I noticed just now that aws-ses tag is also back in circulation despite this tag being cleaned up a while ago: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333834/tag-synonym-amazon-ses-and-aws-ses