# Let's cut down the [amazon]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

There seem to be a lot of tags about AWS products that come in both the `amazon-` and `aws-` variety, but are seemingly describing exactly the same product.

For example:

- [aws-java-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-java-sdk) (45) / [amazon-java-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-java-sdk) (11)
- [aws-rds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-rds) (115) / [amazon-rds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-rds) (1164)
- [aws-ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-ec2) (203) / [amazon-ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2) (14272)
- [aws-lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-lambda) (1248) / [amazon-lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-lambda) (162)
- [aws-mobilehub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-mobilehub) (25) / [amazon-mobilehub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-mobilehub) (8)
- [aws-elasticsearchservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-elasticsearchservice) (29) / [amazon-elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-elasticsearch) (35)
- [aws-kinesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-kinesis) (26) / [amazon-kinesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-kinesis) (260)
- [aws-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-ecs) (22) / [amazon-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ecs) (147)

I've looked at the descriptions for all of these, and they all seem to be about the same products (although I'm not an AWS expert). None of them are tag synonyms. **I think the pairs should be synonymised so that each service/product only has a single, canonical tag.**

I'm not particularly fussed which way the synonym goes. `aws-` allows you to get more characters in the rest of the tag, but it seems like `amazon-` is more common among the other Amazon services.

Comment: Seems like a good idea.  By the way, [tag:aws-ec2] already appears to be a synonym of [tag:amazon-ec2].  This kind of strengthens your suggestion to synonomize the rest of them.

Comment: The fact that [amazon-ec2] is bigger than all the other tags combined also argues toward making amazon-whatever the primary tags.

Comment: You forgot the worst tag of the bunch: [amazon], which should definitely be burned.

Comment: Note that Amazon has preferred nomenclature for its services; some are branded as "Amazon" (EC2, Kinesis) and others as "AWS" (Lambda, Mobile Hub). Tag popularity looks like it generally aligns with the official names, and IMO it'd be best to synonymize along those lines, where length limits permit.

Comment: I don't think this was ever done: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290699/synonyms-amazon-mws-and-mws?rq=1

Comment: This has to be the best title for a burninate/synonym request so far.

Comment: @BhargavRao can this be extended to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-athena and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-athena ? I cannot suggest a tag synonym

Comment: @docendodiscimus Since this question is completed, it would be better to open a new question. I already have https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343482/1558022

Comment: @docendodiscimus looks like alex has sniped us 8 months back. I'll take a look at that post later tonight and try to synonymize those that are obvious.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Current situation (March 2017): all done!

- [aws-java-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-java-sdk) (65) / [amazon-java-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-java-sdk) **Tag gone**
- [aws-rds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-rds) (138) / [amazon-rds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-rds) (1213) **Synonym in place**
- [aws-ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-ec2)  / [amazon-ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2) **Synonym in place**
- [aws-lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-lambda) / [amazon-lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-lambda) **Synonym in place**
- [aws-mobilehub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-mobilehub) (3) / [amazon-mobilehub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-mobilehub) **Tag gone**
- [aws-elasticsearchservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-elasticsearchservice) / [amazon-elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-elasticsearch) (107) **Manually removed tags**
- [aws-kinesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-kinesis) (37) / [amazon-kinesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-kinesis) (283) **Manually removed tags**
- [aws-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-ecs) (25) / [amazon-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ecs) (177) **Manually removed tags**
- [amazon-cloudwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudwatch) (420) / [cloudwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloudwatch) (100) **Synonym in place**

Comment: What does "Need upvoting" mean on that last one?

Comment: It means that [amazon-cloudwatch](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-cloudwatch/synonyms) requires people with a high-enough score to approve the synonym of `cloudwatch`.

Comment: There's only one upvote for the synonym

Comment: Yes. Once 5 people upvote it, it will come true. But they need to have a good score on that tag.

Comment: Meh, @Machavity who has the patience to wait till then. I approved the synonym.

Comment: @BhargavRao [Indeed](https://i.imgflip.com/1lt492.jpg)