# Fire up the chainsaws, there’s still a few trees left in the [amazon]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Previously in “Alex destroys the rainforest”:

- [Let's cut down the [amazon]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334050/1558022)
- [There’s more of the [amazon] to cut down](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343482/1558022)

I’ve found a few more Amazon/AWS related tags that exist in multiple flavours:

- [amazon-cloudfront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudfront) (2576) / [aws-cloudfront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cloudfront) (89)
- [amazon-cloudwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudwatch) (1470) / [aws-cloudwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cloudwatch) (50)
- [amazon-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ecs) (1491) / [ec2-container-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ec2-container-service) (55)
- [aws-opsworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-opsworks) (468) / [opsworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opsworks) (59)
- [aws-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk) (4173) / [amazon-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-sdk) (8)
- [amazon-vpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-vpc) (847) / [aws-vpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-vpc) (149)

I also found two SDK-related tags (the convention elsewhere seems to be `aws-sdk-LANGUAGE`:

- [aws-sdk-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-php) (32) / [aws-php-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-php-sdk) (139)
- [aws-sdk-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-ios) (4) / [awsiossdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awsiossdk) (85)

These tags should be variously retagged or turned into synonyms to make the tagging more consistent.

Comment: @BhargavRao what?! Why haven't I heard about the new toys!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cutting of amazon goes on and on, but we have to do our duty and plant more trees, preferably with eyes.

That said, the following is now done:

- [amazon-cloudfront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudfront) × 2576 ← [aws-cloudfront](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cloudfront) × 89
- [amazon-cloudwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudwatch) × 1402 ← [aws-cloudwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cloudwatch) × 50
- [amazon-ecs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ecs) × 1390 ← [ec2-container-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ec2-container-service) × 55
- [aws-opsworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-opsworks) × 488 ← [opsworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opsworks) × 59
- [aws-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk) × 4174 ← [amazon-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-sdk) × 8
- [amazon-vpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-vpc) × 847 ← [aws-vpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-vpc) × 149
- [aws-sdk-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-ios) × 89 ← [awsiossdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awsiossdk)
- [aws-php-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-php-sdk) × 139 ← [aws-sdk-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-sdk-php) × 32

Notes:

1. John Rotenstein proposed [aws-vpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-vpc) as a synonym for [amazon-vpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-vpc) on Oct 29 '17 at 22:15. I approved it today.
2. There was [vpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vpc) also proposed as a synonym for [amazon-vpc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-vpc), which I deleted.
3. I'll wait for a couple of days and merge these, just to make sure there aren't any issues.