# Why was the datadog tag changed to datadog-api?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Following [advice on meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20tag%20page,name%2C%20and%20confirm%20until%20done.&text=Save%20this%20answer.,-Show%20activity%20on) and asking about tag renames here.

Recently the Datadog tag was changed to [datadog-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datadog-api) with [datadog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datadog) as a synonym. This change incorrectly labels many questions that relate to query syntax, system agents, integrations, types of monitors, custom tags, opentelemetry, and other topics that exist independently of the API.

Can this change be reviewed or is there a discussion that I can review to understand the reasoning for the change? Thanks!

Comment: Seems it was actioned by a Moderator ~15 hours ago, but I can't see any conversation here on Meta about the request for the change.

Comment: I'd guess because [Datadog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datadog) could be considered as [a company tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253910/2821954).

Comment: The existence of `amazon-web-services` as a tag seems to suggest a good amount of subjectivity in what is considered a meta/company tag.

Comment: We used to have amazon: [Let's cut down the \[amazon\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334050/lets-cut-down-the-amazon), so amazon-web-services is a tad better then ...

Comment: The datadog platform is basically a product. I don't think it would be feasible to break it down into individual components. You'd end up with over 50 different tags. `datadog-dashboards`, `datadog-rum` , `datadog-agent`, `datadog-kubernetes-cluster-agent`, `datadog-live-containers`, etc. Plus most questions involve the interaction of all these different products. It's designed to be a single UI with very interlocked components, so most questions will not make sense to tag with anything besides `datadog`

Comment: I've reverted the rename. The rename happened following a discussion in chat, where precisely Andrew's point was mentioned, as well as the observation that most sampled questions were either about the API, or off-topic. The tag likely still needs to be cleaned up, but it's apparently not as straight-forward as initially thought.

Comment: @Zoe That sounds like an answer

Comment: I think [tag:datadog] probably needs a cleanup and disambiguation. Much of what the Datadog company offers are products that are off-topic here. At a glance, questions about the following Datadog products are on-topic here: the API, the Agent, and questions about setting up/implementing logging. Meanwhile many questions, like those about using Datadog Dashboard or about setting up/working with cloud containers like Docker, are off-topic (they should go on Server Fault).

Comment: @draav splitting Amazon in to 50 different tags seemed to work fine. I don't see an issue with splitting datadog, either. The _platform_ as a whole is too broad and not about programming (devops has its own site on the network).

Comment: @TylerH Splitting AWS also didn't replace the utility or need for amazon-web-services as a tag, or it would be gone. Similarly, there's an awful lot of subjectivity involved in which AWS-related topics are and are not programming related, and the approach so far seems to be to be inclusive rather than pedantic about where the line between networking, devops, security, etc is. Perhaps that's related to the scale of AWS, but I'm not sure that's a good reason to apply policy inconsistently.

Comment: @bwest I mentioned Amazon, not AWS. AWS was not split. But many AWS questions are indeed closed as off-topic, like many of these are. The argument I am making, however, is to split Datadog into some kind of set of tags that are themselves on-topic, because Datadog _itself_ is not, and keeping the tag around encourages users that any question about a Datadog product is on-topic, when that is not the case. [AWS] is imperfect in that regard, but it is significantly better than [Amazon]. Users who are interested in a multitude of aspects w/in Datadog can follow along via `[datadog-*]`.

Comment: Of note is that [tag:amazon-web-services] has way more questions, 151 173 ATTOW, so going through each and every one and splitting tags on those is an insurmountable task. [tag:datalog], on the other hand, is manageable for now: only ~1000 questions so far.

Comment: On a similar line of reasoning, that fact there are only 1000 questions and it is manageable and yet still has a closed question rate of ~.5% (vs e.g. ~1.5% for AWS) shows that off-topic questions probably aren't a big issue. Again, I'd like to see what the reasoning that prompted the change in the first place was to have an informed discussion here.

Comment: The observation above doesn't have anything to do with whether the tag should be split or not, just that the existence of other tags shouldn't be used as an argument in discussion about the merits of a given tag.

Comment: That's an interesting perspective but it seems like a matter of opinion. I tend to find lots of value in precedent and working to understand why past decisions were made, especially when they have similarities.